# How to define current timestamp in yaml with doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, timestamp, yaml

I tried the following yaml code:

```
columns:
  created_time:
    type: timestamp
    notnull: true
    default: default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

In the outputted sql statement, the field is treated as datetime instead of timestamp, which I cannot define the current timestamp in it...

If I insist to use timestamp to store current time, how to do so in yaml?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the 'Timestampable' functionality in doctrine, eg:

```
actAs:
  Timestampable:
    created:
      name: created_time
    updated:
      disabled: true
columns:
  created_time:
    type: timestamp
   notnull: true
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are willing to sacrifice some portability (see [description of **columnDefinition** attribute](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column)) for the ability to use MySQL's automatic initialization TIMESTAMP (see [MySQL timestamp initialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)), then you can use the following:

Yaml:

```
  created_time:
    type: datetime
    columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Annotation:

```
@ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

Comment: Hi j0k, thank you for your answer. Made a new topic since I couldnt get it to work with your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208388/symfony-1-4-doctrine-1-yalm-cannot-define-default-timestamp-value

Answer (score 16):

Notice that `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does not work the same as Timestampable, and thus you cannot blindly exchange one for the other.

- First and foremost, the former uses the date/time of the DB server, while the latter uses a Doctrine magic that calls PHP's date() function on your webserver. In other words, they are two distinct ways of getting the date/time, from two entirely different clock sources. You may be on big trouble if you use Timestampable, your web server runs on a different machine than your DB server, and you don't keep your clocks in sync using e.g. NTP.
- Also, the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` being on the table definition makes for a much more consistent database model IMHO, as no matter how you insert the data (for instance, running `INSERT`s on the DB engine command line), you'll always get the current date/time on the column.

BTW, I'm also looking for an answer to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` problem mentioned in the initial question, as this is (due to the reasons outlined above) my preferred way of keeping "timestamp" columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 */
protected $created;
```

---

after run `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force`

> Updating database schema... Database schema updated successfully! "1"
>   queries were executed

and run `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema`

> [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct. [Database] FAIL - The
>   database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

But **FAIL** for sync appear

Comment: WARNING! it's good answer, when you won't update your database from PHP, but do want update structure with migrations or so!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting.
But i have encoutered the same problem. There is solution for doctrine 2 and postgreSql. I have used Gemdo extension and added following strings:

```
 $evm = new \Doctrine\Common\EventManager();

        $timestampableListener = new \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener;
        $timestampableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
        $evm->addEventSubscriber($timestampableListener);
```

YAML:

```
created:
    type: date
    options:
        default: 0
        nullable: true
    gedmo:
        timestampable:
            on: create
updated:
    type: datetime
    options:
         default: 0
         nullable: true
    gedmo:
         timestampable:
             on: update
```

dump-sql:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD created DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users ADD updated TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use `"default"` for timestamp at all.

It will bring unpredictable state in yaml in your application. 
This video ([PHP UK Conference 2016 - Marco Pivetta - Doctrine ORM Good Practices and Tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzGeNYC3oz0&index=8&list=PLKFbhKa6_wX0l8mPt46rLbsOgJHVIPwkk)) provides some more information about this topic.
I suggest you to to go through it and create a named constructor.

```
public function createTimestamp(string $priority, int $priorityNormalized)
{
    $this->priority = $priority;
    $this->priorityNormalized = $priorityNormalized;
}
```

I suggest to be stateless, good luck!

Answer (score -14):

You can use:

```
default: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?>'
```