# Doctrine : Do not insert all fields, only those which aren't NULL

Tags: php, symfony, triggers, doctrine

I have an **Entity**.

```
My\Bundle\Entity\Service:
    type: entity
    table: SERVICE
    fields:
        idService:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            column: ID_SERVICE
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
        codeService:
            type: string
            length: 5
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
            column: CODE_SERVICE
        dateCreation:
            type: date
            nullable: false
            column: DATE_CREATION
        dateModification:
            type: date
            nullable: false
            column: DATE_MODIFICATION
```

In my database, I have a BEFORE INSERT Trigger that set dateCreation and dateModification.

I'd like to let him do his job, but when I persist a new entity, I got this **SQL error** :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO SERVICE (CODE_SERVICE, DATE_CREATION, DATE_MODIFICATION) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["test", null, null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'DATE_CREATION' cannot be null
```

Is there a way to do this ?
I know triggers are bad, but I don't have any choice...

Here is **the trigger**, it works :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `SERVICE_BI_TG` BEFORE INSERT ON `SERVICE` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.DATE_CREATION=NOW();
        SET NEW.DATE_MODIFICATION=NOW();
    END
```

The problem is that I have some other fields set on INSERT or UPDATE, like some foreign key and some UPDATE on other tables, I simplified it for my post.

Comment: Have you got any code for the before insert?

Comment: I updated the initial post with the trigger.

Comment: Where have you set this trigger? Are you doing this via the entity doStuffOnPrePersist() function?

Comment: No, the trigger is created in the database directly..

Comment: So, if I find a way to let him do his job, my entity will not be up-to-date I guess :-/

Comment: If you set a the function in your entity to set a date everytime then yes it will auto update. Also, just set the creation to default to the day as this will never need to be updated, will it?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850693/doctrine-add-default-time-stamp-to-entity-like-now

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is that I have some other fields set on INSERT or UPDATE, like some foreign key and some UPDATE on other tables, I simplified it for my post.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a trigger defined in database for this.

For dateCreation you can initialize it in your entity constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime('now');
}
```

And dateModification you need to a method triggered on preUpdate event:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *  @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class myEntity{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modification", type="datetime")
     */
    private $this->dateModification;

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
     public function incremenDateModification() {
         $this->dateModification = new \DateTime();
     }
}
```

Comment: Will adding this to the constructor not update the creation time, every time?

Comment: Now, will be initialized only once, when object is created. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not looking for a workaround. I know the preUpdate / prePersist and other doctrine events.
But I don't have the choice for triggers, I don't decide :D (I hate triggers too...)

Comment: I suggest you to add the `use ...;` declarations for the ORM annotations, it will be useful to copy and paste your code (only if the user hasn't already used ORM annotations before).

Comment: yes A.L, fair enough, thanks. I missed it, but i added it now