# Symfony 1.4 Doctrine 1 Yaml, cannot define default Timestamp value

Tags: doctrine, timestamp, symfony-1.4, yaml, doctrine-1.2

I have been trying to set  **`TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`** default values for the table columns **`created_at`** and **`updated_at`** in my *schema.yml* as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938655/how-to-define-current-timestamp-in-yaml-with-doctrine).

**System Info:**

- *Symfony 1.4.17*, *Doctrine 1*
- *MySQL 5.6.10*
- *PHP 5.4*

Carefully read the [columnDefinition documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) but couldnt get it to work. As stated in the documentation, `columnDefinition` attribute should be set after the name of the column. After making a migration of the database, the default values set in `columnDefinition` for those columns are not added to the MySQL Database.

Tested changing from `type: timestamp` to `type: datetime`,  but *datetime* its not recognized and running a migrate up, shows an an error message. In the documentation all references about Timestamp type shows it should be declared as: `timestamp`

- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html
- http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files
- https://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/introduction-to-models.html

Also tested adding a `default` value attribute for those columns, but its still not set in MySQL.

**schema.yml:**

```
Tbmdtest005:
  connection: md_test
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
      created:
        name: created_at
        columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        type: timestamp
        format: Y-m-d H:i:s
        options:
          notnull: false
          required: false
      updated:
        name: updated_at
        columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        type: timestamp
        format: Y-m-d H:i:s
        options:
          notnull: false
          required: false
```

**MySQL table:** `tbmdtest005` created in the database after the migration:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbmdtest005` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci
```

**Questions:**

- Is something wrong in my schema.yml?
- Please could you provide a working example?

Comment: Thank you for the edits j0k, a lot better now :)

Comment: If you just leave in your schema `actAs: Timestampable` Doctrine will automatically add the columns `created_at` and `updated_at` and will take care of the proper handling. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thats true Michal, however I need to add the default values for those columns since sometimes I send raw SQLs without using Doctrine. I can perfectly add those default values ALTERING all the tables with an MySQL gui Editor with a simple SQL loop, but still would like to have all my information in the schema.yml if possible.